# What prevents the compiler do a peephole optimization on expression templates?

Tags: c++, assembly, compiler-optimization, expression-templates, peephole-optimization

I have the code listed below:

```
for(auto i =0;i<k;++i)                                                         
    printf("%d\n",(va1+va2-(va1-va2))[i]);
```

where `va1` and `va2` are two `valarray<int>` objects, `k` is the size of `va1` and `va2`. What I am expecting is the compiler optimizes the `printf` line like:

```
printf("%d\n", 2*va2[i]);
```

But instead, both Intel compiler (13.1) and CLang (3.4) did not do such optimization. For example, the Intel compiler outputed the assembly code:

```
..B1.18:                        # Preds ..B1.19 ..B1.17                            
        movl      (%r14,%r15,4), %r9d                           #18.42             
        movl      $.L_2__STRING.1, %edi                         #18.9              
        movl      (%r12,%r15,4), %r8d                           #18.42             
        xorl      %eax, %eax                                    #18.9              
        lea       (%r9,%r8), %esi                               #18.9              
        subl      %r8d, %r9d                                    #18.9              
        subl      %r9d, %esi                                    #18.9              
..___tag_value_main.18:                                         #18.9              
        call      printf                                        #18.9              
..___tag_value_main.19:                                         #                  
                                # LOE rbx r12 r13 r14 r15                          
..B1.19:                        # Preds ..B1.18                                    
        incq      %r15                                          #17.25             
        cmpq      %r13, %r15                                    #17.21             
        jl        ..B1.18       # Prob 82%                      #17.21
```

where `r13` stores the value of `k`, `r14` and `r12` are the beginning of memory of `va1` and `va2`, respectively. `r15` is the iterator variable `i`. From the code, what it does is:

```
load va1[i]
load va2[i]
add va1[i], va2[i] ==> %esi
sub va1[i], va2[i] ==> %r9d
sub %esi, %r9d ==> esi
print %esi
```

Why it is not optimized (even with -O3) to

```
load va2[i]
add va2[i], va2[i] => %esi
print %esi
```

with a peephole optimization? Gcc 4.8.2 does the optimization in this case, but cannot handle `-(va1[i]+va2[i])+(va1[i]-va2[i])`.

It looks like one possible reason is expression templates are used in the code shown previously. Now the question is, why the compiler stopped optimization just one step before perfection? How expression template prevented the step forward?

***NOTE***
Well, the answer can always be "because the compiler is not designed to do that optimization". But as far as I learned from the dragon book, the compiler should do the optimization iteratively until it cannot do anything better.

Comment: `va1+va2-(va1-va2)` is `va2*2,` not va. The entire expression seems invalid to me.

Comment: What do you mean can't handle `-(va1[i]+va2[i])+(va1[i]-va2[i])`? I just tried and it handle as well as the first case (`add va2, va2`, then negate it).

Comment: @EJP It is valid when you have expression template.

Comment: @DanielKO What is your compiler and what is its version?

Comment: @XiaogeSu GCC 4.8.1: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c05c0cff367e0cf5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I assume about C/C++ compiler optimisations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584814/what-can-i-assume-about-c-c-compiler-optimisations)